# How do I fix a metal storm door that is too low on its hinges?

Tags: doors, outdoor, door-frame, hinges, aluminum

We have an aluminum glass door outside of our front door that won't close or open without serious force. It looks like it needs to be lifted on the hinges, as pictured. There is a gap at the top of door and it hits on the bottom of door frame. New homeowner, how can I fix this?

[image: middle hinge]

[image: lower hinge]

Comment: If you lift the door right now, as it is, will it slide upwards a bit and then slide back down when lowered?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it yes. It is very easy to lift the door from the bottom. It will lift to the top of the space shown in pics and slides down immediately when released.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your door is only hinged on that side, it looks like simply unscrewing it and raising it 1/2" (or whatever the gap is) may do you.  Now, that may leave a gap at the bottom, but it's a storm door and that may or may not be a problem—without seeing detail of the threshold who knows?

Or lift the door and insert some spacers in the hinges.

Answer (score 2):

Your hinges are mounted on an *adjustable hinge bar*. The piece that is highlighted in yellow, to which the door hinges are attached, can be unscrewed and adjusted in both *X* and *Y* directions, so the door height and the door width are adjustable.

Typically, a channel which slides up and over the bottom of the door is used to fill any gap at the bottom. That bottom fill channel does not seem to be on your door, so if you adjust it upwards you will either need to live with a gap at the bottom or find some other way to cover it (like maybe a door sweep weatherstrip or something).

Note that changing the hinge bar position will likely require drilling of pilot holes for the screws, at the new position.

[image]

Comment: I think you're right, but that doesn't explain the gap. I'm confused about that point.

Comment: @isherwood I don't suppose it's possible the hinges have simply worn away over the years?

Comment: That was my first thought, but then the flanges wouldn't be at the same level as the barrels. I've seen hinges do that, but they're usually very heavy commercial doors (and steel hinges!).

Comment: @isherwood, you mean the gap above the hinge that you can see in the pics? Yeah that looks... unusual and might be a clue. But I don't see any adjustment available that would close that gap...

Comment: @Huesmann If the hinges were worn down, there would be evidence of aluminum dust at the hinges from the grinding action. The Oilite bushings are still in place.

Comment: @DelphicOracle Maybe?  But given this is an exterior door, much of that dust might have blown away in the wind or washed away by rain before it has a chance to collect in noticeable amounts..

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman This dust is not blown away and is not readily removed by water. It appears as a black dust spreading out from the friction point. It would have to be a driving rain to reach the top hinges and even then you would still see traces. Speaking from 20 years of Aluminum Window experience.

Comment: The door is on a screened in wooden porch. No black marks, but the floor planks  do get wet when it rains a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That gap, is most likely wear and tear from the two bearing surfaces rubbing. Now if the whole door was shown you'll see an equal gap on the upper/middle hinges.
The fix is quite simple.

1. remove the door
2. Pull hinge rod out
3. Take rod to hardware store and get a bunch of small washers, very inexpensive.
4. Reinsert rod into door and frame filling space bellow the hinge to raise the door
5. Repeat 4. For middle lower hinges.
6. Reinstall door
7. Done, go to fridge open beer

Comment: You are correct, the pictures are mid and bottom hinges. Top one is the same. Excellent breakdown- thank-you!